# Attic plasterboard alternative

Tags: drywall, attic, plywood, attic-conversion

I want to avoid using plasterboards under the insulation of my roof and use an alternative instead.

Can I use plywood or some cork boards/sheets or anything else that is light or not as heavy as the plasterboards?

Comment: any particular reason you want to avoid using the finished look of drywall? Its your attic, finish it with whatever you want really. Unless you have concerns about a particular material? (cork sounds odd choice to me)

Comment: i suspect your question is because this is not a living space, and the framing is not up to carrying the weight of drywall and you want a lighter alternative.  I am doing a similar thing in a quanset style workshop, and using 1/8" plywood below my insulation.

Comment: Will this space be a living space or have to meet fire code?

Comment: @markf its not a living space but will be used as kid playroom, cinema room etc. It has UFH. But as you say not sure about the carrying weight.

Comment: @EdBeal in a way it will be living space, maybe we'll use it 1-2 hours a day.

Comment: A family play room or bonus room would be considered a living space not work shop in my jurisdiction so fire resistant materials are required. Sounds funny when the exterior siding can be wood the studs wood but the inside finish being wood stopped the sale of a home for me, we had to put up a layer of Sheetrock then the paneling was ok

Comment: Is it then possible to use cork instead. Let's say with thickness of 4mm or 10mm. Maybe with applying (with glue) some thin battens under the cork. Can something like this be done?